# GetStream: following feed doesn't return the feed's items

Tags: ruby, getstream-io

I've followed the 'tour' on GetStream.io and tried to implement the simplest solution, namely creating a feed, uploading an activity, and then following that feed. In my app I have 'users' and 'artists' which can follow one another. I succeeded in creating an activity on artist:1, which shows up (via the API & dashboard) and I succeeded in letting user:1 follow artist:1 (also confirmed via the dashboard).. now comes the problem:

Even though user:1 follows artist:1 and artist:1's feed has items on it, user:1 feeds stays empty.. so it seems following another feed (even though it's successful) doesn't copy the items from source to target feed..even though that's exactly the way it works in the 'tour'.

below is my code (even though it's quite standard)

```
 def test
      user_feed = client.feed('user', '1')
      artist_feed = client.feed('artist', '1')
      artist_feed.get => #returns items
      artist_feed.followers => #shows user:1 is a follower
      user_feed.get => # nothing?!
    end
```

Am I missing a setting or something? Does anyone have an idea what this could be?
enter image description here
Cheers in advance,

Abel

PS I've added three pictures below of the GetStream dashboard, namely:

1. You see that artist:1 is followed by user:1
2. You see that artist:1 has two activities
3. You see that user:1 has no activities

[image: artist:1 follows]
[image: artist:1 activities]
[image: user:1 activities]

Comment: Have you added activity? Can you post that code as well? Thank you.

Comment: I've added three pictures of the GS dashboard, so that you can actually see that the activity is created :)

Comment: on which feeds were the activities added first? can you include the origin for the three activities?